# Sum two forces with both signs

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to make a good algorithm for summing up pair of forces. The main problem here is that you can have force with alternative sign which means that force can be with + or - at any time.

For example:
F1 = ±100 kN, F2 = 200 kN --> maxForce = +100+200 = 300 kN, minForce = -100+200 = 100 kN.

I've already made an simple algorithm which combines all possibilities, but I ask for something better than that. As an output of my method I have:

```
public List<Force> SumForces(Force firstForce, Force secondForce)
    {
        Force maxForce = new Force();
        Force minForce = new Force();

        // All possible sumatuons
        double sumCaseFirst = firstForce.ForceValue + secondForce.ForceValue;
        double sumCaseSecond = firstForce.ForceValue - secondForce.ForceValue;
        double sumCaseThird = -firstForce.ForceValue + secondForce.ForceValue;
        double sumCaseFourth = -firstForce.ForceValue - secondForce.ForceValue;

        // Calculating all posible sumations
        if (firstForce.Sign == ForceSign.Alter && secondForce.Sign == ForceSign.Alter)
        {
            maxForce.ForceValue = sumCaseFirst;
            minForce.ForceValue = sumCaseFourth;
        }
        else if (firstForce.Sign == ForceSign.Alter && secondForce.Sign == ForceSign.Plus)
        {
            maxForce.ForceValue = sumCaseFirst;
            minForce.ForceValue = sumCaseThird;
        }
        else if (firstForce.Sign == ForceSign.Alter && secondForce.Sign == ForceSign.Minus)
        {
            maxForce.ForceValue = sumCaseSecond;
            minForce.ForceValue = sumCaseFourth;
        }
        else if (firstForce.Sign == ForceSign.Plus && secondForce.Sign == ForceSign.Alter)
        {
            maxForce.ForceValue = sumCaseFirst;
            minForce.ForceValue = sumCaseSecond;
        }
        else if (firstForce.Sign == ForceSign.Plus && secondForce.Sign == ForceSign.Plus)
        {
            maxForce.ForceValue = sumCaseFirst;
            minForce.ForceValue = 0;
        }
        else if (firstForce.Sign == ForceSign.Plus && secondForce.Sign == ForceSign.Minus)
        {
            maxForce.ForceValue = sumCaseSecond;
            minForce.ForceValue = 0;
        }
        else if (firstForce.Sign == ForceSign.Minus && secondForce.Sign == ForceSign.Alter)
        {
            maxForce.ForceValue = sumCaseThird;
            minForce.ForceValue = sumCaseFourth;
        }
        else if (firstForce.Sign == ForceSign.Minus && secondForce.Sign == ForceSign.Plus)
        {
            maxForce.ForceValue = sumCaseThird;
            minForce.ForceValue = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            maxForce.ForceValue = 0;
            minForce.ForceValue = sumCaseFourth;
        }

        // Ensure that true maximum force value is at index 0
        if (maxForce.ForceValue > minForce.ForceValue)
        {
            Sum.Add(maxForce);
            Sum.Add(minForce);
        }
        else
        {
            Sum.Add(minForce);
            Sum.Add(maxForce);
        }


        return Sum;
    }
```

Comment: you have only 2 forces? what is your algorithm?

Comment: @Backs What don't you understand in this statement: `an simple algorithm which combines all possibilities` ?

Comment: it's simple - has all possible combinations of 3 signs and 2 forces combined in if - else if - else block.

Comment: @fjardon the problem is that we dont know how data is represented to show negative and positive force. what data structure we should use in answer.

Comment: Why don't you show your `if`-`else` approach?

Comment: Yes, I will use it to sum list of force pairs, and my algorithm isn't slow, it is just ugly, so I ask for more elegant solution.

Comment: Why `F1` is `+-` and `F2` is only positive? how do you store these values ?

Comment: I've updated question

Comment: Yes, but also one of them can have ± sign, and what I need is possible max and min combinations, for 2 forces it's 9 possible solutions, as I wrote earlier

Comment: did you try creating a map with a key consisting of possible signs, and a value consisting of sumCase for those signs?  that way you don't need all of the if-else statements and just grab the value in your case.

Comment: sorry, but I'm beginner, could you please explan this or maybe give me some reference?

Comment: Dictionary<ForceSign, double> forceMap = new Dictionary<ForceSign,double>();
forceMap.Add(ForceSign.Alter,sumCaseFirst); //Add your signs and their values.  Then access them: forceMap[ForceSign.Alter]

Answer (score 0):

The maximum is always when adding the positive values

```
double maxValue = Math.Abs(firstForce.ForceValue) + Math.Abs(secondForce.ForceValue);
```

The minimum is always when adding the negative values

```
double minValue = -Math.Abs(firstForce.ForceValue) - Math.Abs(secondForce.ForceValue);
```

There is no need to consider the positive and negative combinations.

Comment: You have maxValue twice in variable names

Comment: Yes, but, for example, what if both of them are positive, or negative? Then, max value is sum of them, and there is no min value (it's 0)

Comment: No the min would be equal to the max in this case. Maybe you need to be more clear on the requirements on the form of the forces. I thought each force can either be positive or negative.